# Merge two very similar sets of pytests

Tags: python, pytest

I have got 2 very similar sets of pytests. They basically are run for two parameters and depends on the parameter one of two methods is used (in the same test with the same name). It looks like this:

```
def TestsSetA.test1:
  {CommonPart}
  methodA
  commonMethod(parA)
  {CommonPart}
  {CommonAssertions}

def TestsSetB.test:
  {CommonPart}
  methodB
  commonMethod(parB)
  {CommonPart}
  {CommonAssertions}
```

I suspect there is a way to generate these tests for both params but could you point me in the right direction about how to do that? I don't know what to look for. Parametrization doesn't look like something I need really as I don't want to run exactly the same tests just for 2 params and the expected output (set of assertions) is the same.

Comment: Why is `parametrization` not an option ?

Comment: It's not an option. I just didn't see how that should be done. I probably misunderstood that. I'll try your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `pytest.mark.parametrize` like,

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("para", [1, 2])
def test_a_b(para):
  {CommonPart}
  if para == 1:
    methodA
  else:
    methodB
  commonMethod(para)
  {CommonPart}
  {CommonAssertions}
```

As suggested by, @hoefling, an updated version:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('para,method', [(1, methodA), (2, methodB)])
def test_a_b(para, method):
    {CommonPart}
    method
    commonMethod(para)
    {CommonPart}
    {CommonAssertions}
```

Comment: `@pytest.mark.parametrize('para,method', [(1, methodA), (2, methodB)])` with the signature `def test_a_b(para, method): ...` is a cleaner one IMO.

Comment: @hoefling Yes, it is cleaner. I will update with the recommended changes :)